# My while loop wont end when condition is met

Tags: while-loop, conditional-statements

So what I am trying to do is make a program that makes the user enter a password. If the password is correct, or if there attempts reach a total of 3 the program should stop... but it doesn't.

```
password = "password"
guess = ""
tries = 0

while guess != password or tries != 3:
    guess = input("Password: ")
    tries += 1
    print(f"{abs(tries - 3)} Tries Remaining.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write like this:

```
password = "password"

tries = 0

while True:
    if tries == 3:
         break
    guess = input("Password: ")
    if guess == password:
         break
       tries += 1
    
    print(f"{abs(tries - 3)} Tries Remaining.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional needs to be a logical AND, not a logical OR.

```
while guess != password and tries != 3:
```

When you use a logical OR, the while loop continues if either expression evaluates to true.

So with the logical AND, when `tries == 3`, the second expression evaluates to false and we exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The guess inside the while loop is a local variable , so the global variable remains unchanged. global guess is always '' and so the condition always evaluates to true.